# TDateTime format does not change in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am completely new to C++ Builder environment and quite new to C++ too. So sorry if the question is trivial.
I am trying to change the date format displayed in my application. The date is displayed in a label called `trait_sb_date_lbl`. I want to set the date to the following format : Month (in english, such as January) day and year.

First of, I tried to obtain the month. I tried the following code:

```
    TFormatSettings fmt;
    TDate date;

    fmt.DateSeparator = '-';
    fmt.ShortDateFormat = "mmmm/d/yyyy";
    trait_sb_date_lbl->Caption = DateToStr(date.CurrentDate());
```

I read in the doc that using `mmmm` as a month for format should display the month in full english but this does not work. Even the decimal separator is not displayed, neither the format month/day/year.

Any idea?

Comment: Just a guess, but you aren't actually using `fmt` to format the date …

Comment: This is what I guessed since it wasn't producing any results... Actually I used this example from the docs: ```void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  DateSeparator = '-';
  ShortDateFormat = "m/d/yyyy";
  Label1->Caption = DateToStr(Date());
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FormatDateTime` directly if you don't want to use the current locale settings:

```
TDate date = Date();
trait_sb_date_lbl->Caption = FormatDateTime("mmmm/d/yyyy", date);
```

---

This hardcoded date format is however not so nice if used with a locale such as `sv-SE`. It might be nicer to create a `TFormatSettings` with the selected locale if your app supports a few locales - and use the predefined `LongDateFormat` format in that locale instead.

```
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create("sv-SE"); // one of the supported locales
trait_sb_date_lbl->Caption = FormatDateTime("dddddd", Date(), fmt);
```

Which with `"dddddd"` becomes

```
den 25 Februari 2020   // It's actually lacking the day. It should be "Tisdagen den ..."
```

instead of the `"mmmm/d/yyyy"` version:

```
februari-25-2020
```

The latter is something you'd never use in `sv-SE`.

Comment: This works. However, it displays the date in my locale settings, ie French. I tried to add an extra TFormatSettings parameter at the end after ```date```, by using the ```Create()``` and passing "us-US" argument, but then I loose the formatting.

Comment: Ok my bad for my previous comment, the syntax was incorrect. It works very well even with the formatting. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, you can use `Date()` instead of `Now()`, since you are ignoring the time portion so no need to even retrieve it

Comment: @RemyLebeau True. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing the `fmt` variable with defaults before altering its members.  And you are not passing it to `DateToStr()` afterwards:

```cpp
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
fmt.DateSeparator = '-';
fmt.ShortDateFormat = "mmmm/d/yyyy";
trait_sb_date_lbl->Caption = DateToStr(Date(), fmt);
```

Comment: I can't test it now but I think I did try this Yesterday and I couldn't find that overload for [`DateToStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.DateToStr). The C++ interface only mentions `System::UnicodeString __fastcall DateToStr(const System::TDateTime DateTime)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the overload exists in C++, too

Comment: Indeed - it works - and Today, after changing the code insight settings, the overloads actually show up too. The `Find Declaration` function doesn't do anything though, so I have to manually open `System.SysUtils.hpp` and search for `DateToStr` to see both overloads. :-/